# Logic circuit question

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, logic-gates

Now I have a homework question that isn't quite clear to me.

"Construct a finite state machine that accepts a base 2 value entered one bit at a time with the most significant bit first. The machine output is 1 if the number entered so far (i.e. current state) reflects 2 mod 3 else the output is 0."

now I would have to build a truth table as well as a logical circuit.

I'm confused at where it says 1 bit at a time with the most significant bit first. So the most significant bit would be 1 in base 2, but would I not have to use more than one bit per cycle to structure this? So would this be an error in the question, or am I missing something.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't fault you for being confused. It is a very academically ( poorly) defined problem, not a reality based one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here is more detail.  The state diagram for implementing this as a Moore machine looks like this;
[image]  A Moore machine is one where that states are the outputs.  I always remember this as Mealy machines are more complicated.  From this state diagram the next state and excitation tables can be created.  They look like this;
[image]

Karnaugh maps for each J and K input are used to come up with the logic.  The logic can be seen in this schematic;
[image]
A simulation of this schematic shows an input string that causes the machine to go from state 0 to 1 and back to 0 starting at 2us.  So X = 1,1,0.  Starting a 6us the machine goes from 0 to 1 to 2 and stays there for X = 1,0,1,1.  At 10 us the machine goes from 2 to 1 to 0 for the inputs 1,0.  This has exercised all the transistion possible.  Here is the simulation output;
[image]

Answer (score 3):

When reading a number, MSB first, you only need to keep track of the previous value *modulo 3*, not just the overall previous value, which is easily achievable with a simple transition table and three states. If input is zero, the following transitions can be shown to occur:

- 0 -> 0
- 1 -> 2
- 2 -> 1

If the input is 1, the following transitions occur instead:

- 0 -> 1
- 1 -> 0
- 2 -> 2

according to the rules of modular arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to tie you up too much, as our prof never really went into specifics. So would this be ideal http://imgur.com/zdrg8jM

Comment: @JoshBarber It should be, but you might want to make output 1 for both "b" cases.